# Discord: Stop Exception Error from being printed in Python Console

Tags: python, discord.py

I am sure I am missing something very simple but I just can not find it. I have made a error handle for a command that I made and it responds to the user. The problem is I would like the console of my bot python script to be clean so I am looking for a way to eliminate the large errors that get printed in the console. Even though I handled it, it still prints the exception in the console which is what I am ask to block. Any and all help given is very appreciated.

Code:

```
    @bal.error
    async def bal_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.BadArgument):
            await ctx.send('Balance: Please specify a user. Syntax (!bal {mention})')
        raise error #I am pretty sure there is no need for this.
```

Error that I am trying to avoid being printed to the console:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run
_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\Desktop\AfterClap Bot\bot.py", line 37, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 86
3, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 7
21, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 6
85, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 6
08, in _parse_arguments
    kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 4
55, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 4
08, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 3
54, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
  File "C:\Users\gunzb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", l
ine 132, in convert
    raise BadArgument('Member "{}" not found'.format(argument))
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Member "n" not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that line propagates the error out of the handler, where it is handled by the command invocation logic.  For most errors, that logic will just print the error to `sys.stderr` and then ignore it.

I recommend only re-raising errors if they are not handled by your code:

```
@bal.error
async def bal_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send('Balance: Please specify a user. Syntax (!bal {mention})')
    else:
        raise error # Only called for other errors
```

Comment: I most likely wont have a raise but I dont see how this would prevent the error that gets printed then ignored. My ```bal_error()``` is working as intended but the internal console still prints the error in its full. I will be adding the error to the full body of the question.

Comment: The error is being printed because you are running `raise error` for every error.  Using the above, you would not run it for `BadArgument` errors.  You would probably want other errors to be printed to the console, but if you don't you can remove the `raise` entirely.

Comment: With and without the ```raise``` still prints the ```BadArgument``` error to the console

Answer (score 0):

Return the error to prevent it from printing the error message on the console.

```
@bal.error
async def bal_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send('Balance: Please specify a user. Syntax (!bal {mention})')
        return error
    else:
        raise error
```